# Latest post on specific category and custom css

Tags: get-posts, limit

I'm trying to create a new home page with two columns for latest post of specific category. This the page code:

```
    <div id="left-column"> 
    <div class="bloccorosso">News & Blog</div>  
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=5&posts_per_page=3' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<ul><li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
    </div>

    <div id="right-column">  
    <div class="bloccorossoright">Prossimi Spettacoli</div>
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=6&posts_per_page=3' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li>
<div id="textbox">
<p class="txtclhome"><?php dynamicnews_display_thumbnail_index(); ?> </p>
<h3 class="titlehome"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p class="txtclrhome"><?php the_content_limit(150, ""); ?>
                <a class="morelink" href="http://styleposts.com/?cat=41" rel="bookmark"><?php _e("Read More", 'organicthemes'); ?></a></p> </div></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I create two colum and then I've defined the css style:

```
div#left-column {
 width: 45%;
 float: left;
 clear: none;
 }
div#right-column {
 margin-right: 25px;
 width: 48%;
 float: right;
 clear: none;
 background: #d5d2d2;
 }

.bloccorosso{
background: #C8332A;
height: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
word-spacing: 0.2em;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.bloccorossoright{
background: #C8332A;
height: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
word-spacing: 0.2em;
color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.txtclhome {
    float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.txtclrhome {
float: right;
}

.titlehome{
font-size: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.textbox{
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

I like to have the thumbnail image on left and the prev text align on right of image.

I don't have any problems with the alignment, but I have a problem with the text for different post [screenshot here](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4xv8t/jqmv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the '#textbox' html with the following and css:

```
<div class="textbox">
    <div class="textbox_left">
        <p class="txtclhome"><?php dynamicnews_display_thumbnail_index(); ?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="textbox_right">
        <h3 class="titlehome"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p class="txtclrhome"><?php the_content_limit(150, ""); ?>
        <a class="morelink" href="http://styleposts.com/?cat=41" rel="bookmark"><?php _e("Read More", 'organicthemes'); ?></a></p> </div>
    </div>
</div>

.textbox{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.textbox_left{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.textbox_right{
    width: 38%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

- Never use the same exact names for variables, always make them unique. Naming them the same is confusing and might cause conflicts later on with other non related code. It also makes debugging easier
- You have to reset all instances of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). This is very very important, and one thing that you will have to teach yourself as standard practice. Any query that has not been resetted **will** interfere with any other query on the same page. Simply just add `wp_reset_postdata();` after every completed instance of `WP_Query`. Please refer to the link above for working examples

Unrelated but very important. You should, according to coding standard, properly indent your code. This is not just for the purpose of neatness, but it also makes debugging and general reading of your code so much easier.

You should also avoid using syntaxing like `:` and `endwhile`. It is by no means wrong and is totally valid, but the problem is, most code editors don't support these syntaxing, and therefor makes debugging difficult. Rather use curly brackets (`{}`) which is widely supported by code editors